# How can I change the textScrollList depending upon the options I have selected in optionMenu in Maya?

Tags: python, maya, pymel, maya-api

`
This is the function that i wrote the operation, where om = optionMenu

```
def selection(*args):
    
    selected = cmds.optionMenu(om,sl=True, q=True) 
       
    cmds.textScrollList(tsl, e=True, removeAll=True)
    
    
    for item in temp[selected]:
        cmds.textScrollList(label=item, parent=om)
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuofL.png)

So basically I have object types in the OM and all the objects in TSL, I wanna display items of only selected object types from OM, for example if I select "mesh" in the OM the TSL will display only mesh objects.

where OM = optionMenu
and TSL - textScrollList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get a qualified answer, you should provide a minimal executable script. And you did not write what exactly does not work. Please describe exactly what errors you get. What I can see is that you create a list of textScrollList ui elements instead of filling the existing text scroll list. A complete solution can look like this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class MyWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.types = ["mesh", "light"]    
        self.tsl = None
        self.win = None
        self.om = None
        self.buildUI()

    def updateList(self, *args):
        geoType = cmds.optionMenu(self.om, query=True, value=True)
        cmds.textScrollList(self.tsl, edit=True, removeAll=True)
        elements = cmds.ls(type=geoType)
        for e in elements:
            cmds.textScrollList(self.tsl, edit=True, append=e)
            
    def buildUI(self):
        if self.win is not None:
            if cmds.window(self.win, exists=True):
                cmds.deleteUI(self.win)
        self.win = cmds.window()
        cmds.columnLayout()
        self.om = cmds.optionMenu(cc=self.updateList)
        for i in self.types:
            cmds.menuItem(label=i)
        self.tsl = cmds.textScrollList()

cmds.showWindow(self.win)
```

I use a class here because it is easier to maintain and to keep all data inside.

Comment: Thanks for you response it worked for me , and from now on i'll make sure to add the minimum executable code rather than just a bit of it.